# How to modify message data in CAPL if message is generated by Interactive generator block?

Tags: can-bus, capl, canoe, canalyzer

I am using CANalyzer.
I am transmitting CAN message using Interactive Generator block. I use IG to modify signals in transmitted message by hand.
I need to automaticaly calculate checksum (the last byte in the message) every time the message is sent. Checksum is calculated from all previous data bytes in the message (message is always 8 bytes long). There is no option in IG to do that.

I need:

1. Set signals by hand using IG.
2. Automatically calculate value of the last data byte according to values of preceding data bytes.

I tried to write simple code in CAPL but without success.
I put CAPL Program node after the IG node in the Configuration window and wrote on message event in CAPL script:

```
on message FooMsg
{
  message FooMsg msg1; // FooMsg is name of message in database
  
  msg1 = this; // copy message from IG to temporary variable
  // this.byte(7) = 0x11; // not posibble, compiler warning
  msg1.byte(7) = 0x11;  // constant value just for test
  output(msg1); // send message
}
```

The message is transmitting but the Tx period set in IG is not respected (message is transmitted as fast as possible).

I thought I catch the message generated from IG, modify it and send to CAN bus.

Comment: Why are you using a 8 bit checksum in the payload, when there's a 15 bit checksum in the CAN frame, calculated by the controller hardware? This smells of poorly considered design.

Comment: @Lundin This is called application layer CRC check, and is more common than you think. See TimeSync protocol for instance over CAN/FR. 

ZM81 forget the IG, create a panel with fields which will modify sysvars. These sysvars will be mapped to your CAN signals, or CAN payload bytes more precisely. The automatic sending and calculation you will have to do from CAPL code, but not with on event as you wrote the example. Please read what on events do, and how to create a Panel in CANoe, these are basic know-hows which you must understand.

Comment: @VioletVynil If there is a checksum in the application layer then something is wrong with the design. If you use CAN together with some other manner of protocol, you need to separate data link layer from application layer. For example if you first send the data over UART, you need a CRC in a carrier protocol. If the same data is then passed on to CAN, you shouldn't be passing on the CRC as well. Hence design smell. ->

Comment: The only valid case of application layer CRC I can think of is when you have an external CAN controller using SPI etc. But that too is design smell/Arduino-quackery, since microcontrollers come with built-in controllers since 20 years ago.

Comment: The Application layer CRC is calculating CRC only on the payload, contrary to the data link layer CRC field, which as a whole protects the Protocol Data Unit. 
The need for CRC layering in Application layer (the double boxing effect) arise for safety critical functionalities, as in Automotive/Aviation industry, Passive Safety Algorithms and Active Safety Algo. Without it, the Functional Safety standard reqs for E2E protection are not met. 
Indeed, somewhat smells, because it is pure paranoia, but it is the least paranoid methodology in embedded systems, if you ask me.

Comment: @VioletVynil You always have to meet such safety requirements with rational arguments. There's a whole lot in the functional safety standards which simply doesn't make sense. Following them blindly introduces safety hazards in the product - you should always add functional safety standards as a major hazard during risk assessment. But well, if you have reason to suspect that the data between the MCU and transceiver might be exposed to EMI, then it makes sense to use a payload CRC - that's a rational argument. "Standard x says so" is not.

Comment: As with everything data communication, increasing message length increases probability for corruption. So if you have 1 byte payload and 1 byte 8-bit CRC, you might actually have reduced the safety of the system, as you increased the probability of the packet getting hit by EMI corruption by 100%. The 8 bit CRC might not necessarily decrease the probability as much, since it mostly added a better chance of detecting single bit errors.

Comment: @ Lundin I can stand behind that rule of thumb that every safety relevant implementation should make sense before the need of standard compliance.

Comment: @Lundin But still 80% of Automotive OEMs require such safety measures. And I guess I know why: the 1 size fits all SW Architectures applied. The road is too long from app layer to CC, passing interfaces and assignment operations. A bitflop can happen any time in payload even before it reached the Communication Controller.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I redesigned the whole stuff as VioletVynil recommended.
I created panels, add system variables and hooked them to controls on panels, wrote some code in CAPL for calculating checksum and periodic transmit of the message and it runs! Without any problems! And yes additional CRC on the payload is used for additional safety (railway application). I didn't designed communication protocol, I just got it.